# How do I restrict certain drives from auto-mounting in Windows Subsystem for Linux WSL with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hard-drive, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bitlocker, wsl2, google-drive-for-desktop

- Windows 10
- WSL2
- Ubuntu 20.04

Of the 26 available Windows 10 drive letters/mount points, unfortunately I am using them all.

Hard drive (B:) is a Google Drive and drive (R:) is locked with Bitlocker. Is there a way (using wsl.conf .wslconfig or other config file or script) to ignore, avoid or automatically dismount these drives on the start-up of WSL?

The WSL Debug console is reporting errors and I believe it's related to these drives:

```
[ 6454.316320] 9pnet_virtio: no channels available for device drvfs
[ 6454.421475] 9pnet_virtio: no channels available for device drvfs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may disable the auto-mount in WSL of all Windows disk.
This will require to define the disks that you do wish to mount
in the file `/etc/fstab`.

You will find more information in the Microsoft article
[Advanced settings configuration in WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config).

According to the documentation you need to do the following
(I haven't tried it myself).

`/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[automount]
# Automatically mount Windows drive when the distribution is launched plus /etc/fstab
enabled = false
# Sets the `/etc/fstab` file to be processed when a WSL distribution is launched.
# Redundant if enabled = true
mountFsTab = true
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# Mount local C:\ drive
C: /mnt/c drvfs defaults 0 0
```

You will need to create the `/mnt/c` directory yourself.